# New receiver with higher epoch Error in EventProcessorHost

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I am using EventProcessorHost for reading Eventhub data and i got following error.

> New receiver with higher epoch of '798393595' is created hence current
>   receiver with epoch '17' is getting disconnected. If you are
>   recreating the receiver, make sure a higher epoch is used.
>   TrackingId:6368f7fc0004165d0001c7bb58238501_G34_B22,
>   SystemTracker:dynmsg-push-evidence:eventhub:push-assignment-execute~28671|dsreporting,
>   Timestamp:11/9/2016 8:21:32 PM

Note - I am not using EventHubReciever and used only EventProcessorHost way to read data from event hub. I can see first time it will run and read data from event hub but after that it will always throw error like above?

I there anyway we can avoid Epoch value to read data? Assuming i only want to achieve this using EventProcessorHost.

```
eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(eventProcessorHostName,config.EventHubSourceName, string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.EventHubSourceConsumerGroup)? EventHubConsumerGroup.DefaultGroupName:config.EventHubSourceConsumerGroup,
                    config.EventHubSourceConnectionString, config.StorageConnectionString)
                {
                    PartitionManagerOptions = new PartitionManagerOptions()
                    {
                        AcquireInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                        RenewInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                        LeaseInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                    }
                };

                var eventProcessOption = new EventProcessorOptions
                {
                    InvokeProcessorAfterReceiveTimeout = true,
                    MaxBatchSize = 100,
                    PrefetchCount = 100,
                    ReceiveTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                };

                eventProcessOption.ExceptionReceived += EventProcessOption_ExceptionReceived;

                var factory = new EventHubHostFactory(config.FileName, CallbackEventHubData);
               // var eventFactory = new DefaultEventProcessorFactory<factory>();

                await eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorFactoryAsync(factory, eventProcessOption);
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: edited question with code

Comment: Don't have an answer, but you might find some help [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gyan/2014/09/02/event-hubs-receiver-epoch/)

Comment: Were you able to find anything?

Answer (score 0):

From experience, this error is given by the use of the same consumer group of two or more applications.
Check that you do not already have an application that retrieves data from that consumer group. And clear checkpoint files too.